Combine duplicate rows on Excel with the "non-blank" value?
I have a spreadsheet with duplicate names, but each row has different columns where things are blank. Is it possible to remove the duplicates in a way that keeps the non-blank value, or keep the value of the longest string?
Looking to turn this:

screenshot of spreadsheet, with Jane + John 2 rows each

Into this:
screenshot of desire results, where Jane + John is deduped. Jane's row should be a combination of the duplicate rows.


I'm not sure if there are any functions that would readily do this, but, in theory, you could get the results into a pivot table, looking the way you want them to look, and then just copy and paste the pivot table contents out to another sheet.  Are you familiar with using pivot tables?

What's your rule going to be if there are two different values, for the same column, across a particular person's duplicate rows?  Or are you 100% confident that it's always a case of a value on one of the rows and empty cell on the "other" row?

Actually, in reference to my first comment, it's probably a solution that would require some Power Query to get the desired output

I've done pivot tables + power query before, but not super familiar with it. For your 2nd comment, I would actually prefer keeping the longer string, so if 1 row says "CEO" and the 2nd row says "Chief Exec Officer", I want the latter to be displayed.

Having some particular logic like that might make things more difficult - given that even with some kind of grouping (to consolidate rows) in Power Query, you'd likely be using some aggregation functions like MAX(), or similar - which may not ultimately give you the desired result in certain circumstances

You can fill in the blank space first, and then use the Unpivot feature in Power Query.

Do you have access to either 365 or Power Query?

I have access to Power Query. Which functions should I use for this: You can fill in the blank space first, and then use the Unpivot feature in Power Query.

Since you indicated you had access to Power Query, you can use this sample M code to accomplish your goals.
The "magic" happens within the Table.Group function as you fill in the blank rows:

//Change next line to reflect actual data table
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table13"]}[Content],
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"First Name", type text}, {"Last Name", type text}, {"title", type text}, {"city", type text}, {"State", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"First Name", "Last Name"}, {
        {"all", (t)=>Table.Distinct(Table.FillUp(Table.FillDown(t, Table.ColumnNames(t)),Table.ColumnNames(t))) , 
        
        type table [First Name=nullable text, Last Name=nullable text, title=nullable text, city=nullable text, State=nullable text]}}),
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "all", {"title", "city", "State"}, {"title", "city", "State"})
in
    #"Expanded all"

Note that because of the use of the Table.Group, you can consolidate as many rows per person as you have, and they do not have to be in any particular order.

Solution with formulas and the Remove Duplicates tool.

Copy the columns with First Name and Last Name to another location (in the example, A8:B12)

For C9, type the formula:
=INDEX(C$2:C$5,MATCH(MAX(LEN(C$2:C$5)*($A$9:$A$12=$A9)*($B$9:$B$12=$B9)),LEN(C$2:C$5)*($A$9:$A$12=$A9)*($B$9:$B$12=$B9),0))
Confirm by Ctrl+Shift+Enter (in the new Excel, Enter is enough)

Copy the formula across the entire range (in example, C9:E12)

Select a range of cells with data and formulas (A9:E12 in example)

Apply the Remove Duplicates tool.



In the new version of Excel (365), you can apply the recently introduced GROUPBY function and get the result in one step.
=GROUPBY($A$1:$B$5,$C$1:$E$5,LAMBDA(x,CONCAT(UNIQUE(IF(MAX(LEN(x))=LEN(x),x,"")))),3,0)


I don't believe the Remove Duplicates tool appeared until 2016, and he has tagged 2007 and 2010.

@Ron Rosenfeld, I still have the 2007 version, I checked, there is Remove Duplicates in that version.

I didn't realize it was present that early. But I no longer have access to 2007. Thanks for checking.

I actually have the latest MacOS Excel, but thank you, this works! Is there a way to scale this for the entire sheet, based on the first name + last name? For example, let's just say there's 5 rows of "John Smith", 3 rows of "Jane Anders", 6 rows of "Angie Smith" - could I combine the data?

I think so. Have you tried and encountered a problem?
